# Dynamic UIScrollView IOS

Tags: ios, xcode, dynamic, uiscrollview

my problem related to scroll view(first look at the image). I want to make it dynamic, so when I press plus on secondView, under it appears third view with plus button, when pressed it goes upper, and so on.. how to make change the height of ScrollView dynamically

[image: it is sketch of my view placed in scroll view]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create dynamic `scrollView` please follow this step.

### #Dynamic Scroll View

#### ScrollContainerView-1

After adding `scrollView` add another view inside `scrollView` and named it `scrollContainerView` this view will handling the `scrolling`.
Set `top`, `left`, `right`, `bottom` constraints to zero like this.
[image]

Now ctrl-drag you `scrollContainerView` to `scrollView` and select both constraint `equalWidth` & `equalHeight`.

[image]

Now you will see two parallel `equalWidth` & `equalHeight` constraint lines `vertically` and `horizontally`. If you want to `horizontalScrolling` select horizontal parallel lines and select vertical for vertical scrolling.
We are selecting `vertical` lines and change the priority from `1000` to `750`. After setting `750` vertical parallel line will become **dashed lines**

[image]

#### ScrollContentView

Now add third and last view in `scrollContainerView` this is the actual `contentView` all of you programatically adding views should be add in this view.
Set `top`, `left`, `right`, `bottom` constraints to zero and also set height of your `contentView`. Make `IBOutlet` of this height constraint and change it according to views added in this contentView.

[image]

### Note:

> If you add 5 `smallViews` in `contentView` with size 80 and with 10 points of vertical spacing between each view. Then the height of `contentView` should be (80 * 5) + (10 * (5-1)) = 440.

Comment: Thank you for brief explanation! I will try soon!

Comment: It works when I set priority to 250, and also I didn't set any height to contentView, it changes dynamically.

Comment: because you might be setting every constraints that helps contentView to calculate its height just like you set constraint in a `UITableViewCell` to set cell height as `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `UITableView` for this requirement, You can keep one `Add button` on each cell and on click of the first cell Add the second cell and reload the tableView and so on.

```
self.tableView.reloadData();
```

I hope this helps.